# How to expose open-API endpoint in spring cloud and azure application

Tags: azure-functions, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-generator-cli

I am trying to use open API in spring cloud and Microsoft azure functions but I am unable to expose the open API URL. In the console (attached image), you can see I have only one api endpoint which is referring to my spring cloud and azure function. I am using open API specs but not getting the Open-API UI link.
So my question is, do I need to create an azure function to expose the open API URL? if yes how if not then what I am doing wrong!
Thanks in advance

[image]

Functions:

```
    adapter: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

- We need to Use Azure API management for generating [OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition) in Azure functions.
- Now the API management has Consumption tier as well, which would be best for custom gateway for azure functions.
- This should work for spring cloud functions deployed on azure functions too.

Comment: What if I am trying to run it locally?

Comment: The above instructions were already done by me, but the problem is i cant access the open-api/Swagger while running the azure funcitons!